# Allow WooCommerce Gateway Percentage Fee to work also on order pay

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, fee

I've been using this snippet for a while with no issue until I noticed that a customer was able to pay by credit card without being charged a fee. They managed to make a payment via the "order-pay" page.

Can anyone tell me why my code isn't working on the order-pay page? It works fine on the checkout page.

```
// Assign Credit Card Gateway Percentage Fee to Wholesaler Profiles

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'sm_credit_card_fee_role_gateway', 10, 1);
function sm_credit_card_fee_role_gateway($cart){
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    if (!(is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()))
        return;

    if (!is_user_logged_in())
        return;

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = (array) $user->roles;
    $roles_to_check = array('administrator', 'default_wholesaler', 'wholesaler-non-vat-registered', 'shop_manager');
    $compare = array_diff($roles, $roles_to_check);

    if (empty($compare)){
        $payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
        if ($payment_method == 'cardgatecreditcard'){
            $percentage = 0.085;
            $surcharge = (WC()->cart->cart_contents_total + WC()->cart->shipping_total) * $percentage;
            $cart->add_fee( 'Credit Card Fee (8.5%)', $surcharge, true );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow your code to be active on Order pay, you may replace in your code:

```php
if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
    return;
```

by:

```php
if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) )
    return;
```

Now your function code will also be executed on WooCommerce **Order Pay** endpoint…

> But in **Order Pay** endpoint, the data is saved to an existing order, **so the fee is already saved** for this order when order was placed in checkout. The hook `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` affect only the cart object **and doesn't have any effect on an exiting order** in Order Pay endpoint.
>
> You will have to rebuilt something much more complicated specifically for Order Pay, involving certainly Ajax, to be able to remove or add your custom fee in the existing order, refreshing totals…

Comment: Didn't work. I tested by removing all other functions. I also tried 'order-pay'.

Comment: Seems that the order-pay page does not use AJAX to update the payment method. I don't believe there is a work around for this... https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/10764

Comment: I've just come across the same issue experienced by other people. Seem that there is a work around but might involve writing code specifically for the order-pay endpoint. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fees-not-changing-on-checkout-order-pay-endpoint/

Comment: The question I should have asked is "Is it possible to add Gateway Fees to an existing order in the order-pay endpoint?". I'm not sure this possible in WooCommerce.

Comment: @WanderlustConsulting I have updated my answer, giving you the reasons why your code doesn't work in Order pay. Everything is possible in WooCommerce, but what you need to do is something much more advanced that requires Ajax triggered by the payment gateways change (or post refreshing the page).

Comment: Thank you for your honest assessment. What I'm actually trying to achieve is as follows: I sell retail and wholesale. When a wholesaler buys a certain product, they must select "request a quote" shipping option which at this point is zero. By selecting"request a quote", I offset "credit card" and only allow "baacs". The order is generated, the shipping costs are added and it's at this point that I want to give my wholesaler the option to pay by credit card. So I want to add a fee in the order-pay endpoint if they choose credit card. Will this take alot of coding? I'm no coder but I can learn.

Comment: @WanderlustConsulting For Wholesale users roles, this requires in Order pay to add a fee to the order when credit card is selected or to remove it if they change their mind and choose BACS. For the moments I don't know how I would do that and how many time it will take as I have never do it before yet. But this is doable for sure.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that this is doable. I am very happy to work together to come up with a solution for the WooCommerce community. Then we can publish it here to help other people with the same problem. I can set-up a staging and we can thrash out some ideas on how to get the endpoint to update the order when a customer changes the payment method. Can we do it?

Comment: @WanderlustConsulting Sorry but if you don't know how to handle this problem, you will have to hire a developer. I only answer / help here in StackOverFlow on some selected questions, when I have time.

Comment: It seems TycheSoftwares has resolved this issue in their Pro version. They will be releasing it to their Free Lite version soon. https://github.com/TycheSoftwares/checkout-fees-for-woocommerce